# Syntax to convert 'Nov 23, 2019, 1:44 PM' to a datetime like 2019-11-23 13:44:25.000 format?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, type-conversion, datetime-format

I have been looking for a solution to convert one of my data fields which is in 'Nov 23, 2019, 1:44 PM' and has a datatype of a `nvarchar`. When I use `convert(datetime,[Exam Scheduled Date/Tm],121)` I get a error of

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: If you check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the closest format to what you are using is 107. However you still need to use some string manipulation to remove the comma after the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TRY_PARSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) function appears to work:

```
DECLARE @DateString nvarchar(50) = 'Nov 23, 2019, 1:44 PM';

SELECT TRY_PARSE(@DateString AS datetime USING 'en-us')
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that [format "107"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is *forgiving* about whether there is a comma or not, so just replace all commas first then convert using format "107".

```
select convert(datetime, replace([Exam Scheduled Date/Tm],',',''),107)
from (
  select 'Nov 23, 2019, 01:44 PM' [Exam Scheduled Date/Tm]
) X
```

Answer (score -2):

try `convert(datetime,REPLACE([Exam Scheduled Date/Tm],',',' '),100)`

Comment: Have you tried it? 'Nov 23,2019, 1:44PM' returns 2019-11-23 13:44:00.000.